# UI side restApi call and then close the UI screen what will happen

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, java-8, threadpool, spring-restcontroller

**ReactJS Front End Axios call to Java 1.8 Spring based Rest API.**

what happend from Front END UI side we call the REST API to Backend Server and we find that its taking to much time to return the status.

Then what will happen on server side ?
UI side as we leave the thread so what will happen that time ?

May be Frond end side thread is left then on Server side thread will get kill.

Answer (score 0):

When a ReactJS front-end makes an Axios call to a Java 1.8 Spring-based REST API, several things can happen when the API takes a long time to return a response:

1. **Front-End Behavior**: On the front-end side (ReactJS), when an Axios call is made, it is an asynchronous operation. While waiting for the response, the front end can continue with other tasks and won't be blocked by the API call. Depending on how you handle the response, you may update the UI or perform other actions when the response is received.
2. **Backend Server Behavior**: On the server side (Java 1.8 Spring-based REST API), if the API call is taking too much time to process, several scenarios can occur:

   - If the API call is synchronous (i.e., the server waits for the processing to complete before sending the response), the thread handling the API call will be occupied until the processing is done. If your application uses a limited number of threads and all available lines are occupied, incoming requests may be queued, leading to potential delays for other users.
   - If the API call is asynchronous (i.e., the server doesn't wait for the processing to complete before sending a response), the response may be sent to the front end before the processing is finished. However, the actual processing will continue on another thread or in the background. This approach can help free up server resources, but it requires proper handling of asynchronous operations.
3. **Timeouts and Error Handling**: In both the front-end and back-end, you should handle timeouts and potential errors. For the front end, you may set a timeout for the Axios call to avoid waiting indefinitely. For the back end, you can implement mechanisms to handle long-running processes and provide appropriate responses or error messages when necessary.
4. **Thread Handling**: On the server side, the application server or container manages the threads. Long-running API calls can potentially tie up threads, which may affect the overall responsiveness of your application. It's essential to configure your server and application to handle concurrent requests efficiently.
5. **Scaling and Performance**: If your application experiences frequent long-running API calls, it may be an indication that the server needs to be scaled to handle more concurrent requests or that optimizations are needed to improve processing efficiency.

To handle long-running API calls, consider using techniques such as asynchronous processing, thread pooling, and managing timeouts appropriately. Additionally, monitoring and performance testing can help identify bottlenecks and optimize your server's behaviour.